# S2VUtils.getConnectionToVerticaHost(): FATAL ERROR. cound not get connection to any host in list

Tags: java, apache-spark, vertica

I am trying to connect my Java based Apache Spark application to Vertica database using HPE Vertica Spark Connector and I'm getting following exception. The IP Address mentioned is the IP address of Vertica VM installed on my machine. I get that IP address by executing command "ifconfig" on VM.

**Environment:**

- vertica-7.2.3_ovf
- VMware-player-12.1.1-3770994
- Windows 10
- apache spark-1.6.2
- hpe-vertica-spark-connector-0.2.2

**Code:**

```
HashMap<String, String> verticaConnectorProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
verticaConnectorProperties.put("table", "testtable");
verticaConnectorProperties.put("db", "testdb");
verticaConnectorProperties.put("user", "testuser");
verticaConnectorProperties.put("password", "testpassword");
verticaConnectorProperties.put("host", "192.168.10.10"); // IP of Vertica VM installed on this machine
dataFrame.write()
        .format("com.vertica.spark.datasource.DefaultSource")
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .options(verticaConnectorProperties)
 .save();
```

**Error:**

```
16/08/08 14:38:57 INFO S2VUtils: current partitions in DataFrame=2; S2V default value=16; user option numPartitions=16; final S2V numPartitions for save=2
16/08/08 14:38:57 INFO S2VUtils: All user options and S2V options validated ok: temp_table=S2V_TEMP_TABLE_testtable_S2V_job4115324674851267391, strlen=1024, save_mode=Overwrite, last_committer_table=S2V_TEMP_TABLE_testtable_S2V_job4115324674851267391_last_committer, host=192.168.10.10, num_partitions=2, tmpdir=/tmp, db=testdb, empty_count=-1, job_name=S2V_job4115324674851267391, all_done_table=S2V_JOB_STATUS, commit_tables_prefix=S2V_TEMP_TABLE_testtable_S2V_job4115324674851267391_commits_partition, dbschema=public, port=5433, autocommit=false, log_rejected_rows_sample_size=10, primary_ip=192.168.10.10, failed_rows_percent_tolerance=0.0, batch_size=100000, user=dbadmin, table=testtable, password=MASKED
16/08/08 14:38:57 INFO S2VUtils: Unique job name:S2V_job4115324674851267391 will appear in Vertica table: public.S2V_JOB_STATUS
16/08/08 14:38:57 INFO S2V: Vertica node IPs mapping=Map(127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1)
16/08/08 14:38:57 INFO S2V: Vertica node IPs that will be used by the connector=List(127.0.0.1)
16/08/08 14:38:58 ERROR S2VUtils: ERROR: getConnectionToVerticaHost(): ConnectException: java.lang.NullPointerException
16/08/08 14:38:58 ERROR S2VUtils: ERROR: ConnectException: java.lang.Exception: ERROR: S2VUtils.getConnectionToVerticaHost(): FATAL ERROR. cound not get connection to any host in list:'List(127.0.0.1)'.
16/08/08 14:38:58 INFO S2VUtils: createTempTables(): creating all temp tables now...
16/08/08 14:38:59 ERROR S2VUtils: ERROR: getConnectionToVerticaHost(): ConnectException: java.lang.NullPointerException
16/08/08 14:38:59 ERROR S2VUtils: ERROR: ConnectException: java.lang.Exception: ERROR: S2VUtils.getConnectionToVerticaHost(): FATAL ERROR. cound not get connection to any host in list:'List(127.0.0.1)'.
16/08/08 14:39:00 ERROR S2VUtils: ERROR: getConnectionToVerticaHost(): ConnectException: java.lang.NullPointerException
16/08/08 14:39:00 ERROR S2VUtils: Error: Update statement: CREATE table public.S2V_TEMP_TABLE_testtable_S2V_job4115324674851267391 (sd_enodeb_name LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_managed_object2 LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_cell_name LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_vendor LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_status LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_date_onair LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_long_wgs84 DOUBLE PRECISION,
sd_lat_wgs84 DOUBLE PRECISION,
sd_height DOUBLE PRECISION,
sd_azimuth DOUBLE PRECISION,
sd_cluster LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_operator LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_region LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_province LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_city LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_projection_utm LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_earfcn_dl INTEGER,
sd_freq_band LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_freq_type LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_horizontal_beamwidth INTEGER,
sd_node_type LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_enodeb_id INTEGER,
sd_cellid INTEGER,
sd_cell_type LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_tal LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_tac INTEGER,
sd_pci INTEGER,
sd_frequency LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_mcc LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_mnc LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_antenna LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_e_tilt LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_m_tilt LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_ne LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_engineer LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_cell_coverage LONG VARCHAR (1024),
sd_siteatt LONG VARCHAR (1024) ). java.lang.Exception: ERROR: S2VUtils.getConnectionToVerticaHost(): FATAL ERROR. cound not get connection to any host in list:'List(127.0.0.1)'.
16/08/08 14:39:00 ERROR S2VUtils: createTempTables(): FAILED to create table public.S2V_TEMP_TABLE_testtable_S2V_job4115324674851267391
16/08/08 14:39:00 ERROR S2VUtils: createTempTables(): FAILED to create table public.S2V_TEMP_TABLE_testtable_S2V_job4115324674851267391_last_committer
16/08/08 14:39:01 ERROR S2VUtils: ERROR: getConnectionToVerticaHost(): ConnectException: java.lang.NullPointerException
16/08/08 14:39:01 ERROR S2VUtils: ERROR: ConnectException: java.lang.Exception: ERROR: S2VUtils.getConnectionToVerticaHost(): FATAL ERROR. cound not get connection to any host in list:'List(127.0.0.1)'.
16/08/08 14:39:01 ERROR S2VUtils: createTempTables(): FAILED to create table public.S2V_JOB_STATUS
16/08/08 14:39:02 ERROR S2VUtils: createTempTables(): FAILED to create tables public.S2V_TEMP_TABLE_testtable_S2V_job4115324674851267391_commits_partition_0...1
16/08/08 14:39:02 ERROR VerticaSparkConnectorLoader: Error in saveToVertica
java.lang.Exception: ERROR: S2V.save(): Failed to setup the temp tables to track Spark partition commits.
 at com.vertica.spark.s2v.S2V.save(S2V.scala:117)
 at com.vertica.spark.datasource.DefaultSource.createRelation(VerticaSource.scala:77)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:222)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)
 at my.java.File(MyJavaFile.java:54)
```

Comment: Seems strange that it would try to connect to localhost when you specified the host otherwise. Do you have native load balancing enabled in Vertica?

Comment: I didn't explicitly configured any additional parameters or options on Vertica VM, just installed it as it was downloaded from HPE. Does native load balancing is enabled by default? plus I'm running it on a single VM in my laptop, as standalone Vertica instead of cluster.

Comment: I'm just trying to imagine some way that it would try to connect to 127.0.0.1 instead of the host you have configured. Like if the NLB returned the wrong address to connect to or something crazy. It should not be on by default, though. The only other think I can think of is that somehow your connection params aren't making it to the connect and it isn't obvious in the short snippets you have above. Maybe someone else has better ideas.